# Short-term visa rules stated in Denmark website

Tags: visas, denmark

> If you have a visa that is valid for multiple entries for at least 6 months you can hand in an application for a new visa before the current visa expire. If you are granted a new visa it will be an extension of the current visa. You can therefore enter on the first visa and then exit on the other visa provided that the conditions for both the visas including the rule of the 90 days within the 180 days in Schengen region are observed.

(from [New to Denmark.dk](http://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/visa/duration/how_long.htm))

Questions:

1. To be the extension of current visa, should the new visa be the exactly same type of the current one? For example, my current one is 2 entries valid for 225 days with 90days stay in maximum. if the new one is just one entry, valid for 2 months, 30 days stay. Is it the extension of my current visa?
2. To be qualified to enter one first visa exit on the another visa, do both visas need to include the rule of 90 /180 days? does it indicate that both visas must be multiple entry visas?
3. Does my current visa (2 entries, 90days stay in maximum, valid for 225days) include the rule of 90/180 days?

Answer (score 2):

In order:

1. The paragraph is a bit confusing, it seems to reflect article 9 of the [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810) (“Holders of a multiple-entry visa may lodge the application before the expiry of the visa 
   valid for a period of at least six months.”) and the relevant part of the *Handbook for the processing of visa applications and the modification of issued visas* but goes beyond what's really in this regulation. Nowhere in the official text is there any mention that the new visa would be an “extension”, extensions are for other, very limited purposes.
2. I don't see anything in the official regulations implying that entering on a visa and leaving on another is something that would be limited to some visas but not others. My understanding is that if you do have two back-to-back visas without gap, you could do that. But since single and two-entry visas should be issued for specific trips, it shouldn't happen, which is why it's mostly relevant for multiple-entry visas.
3. The 90/180 rule applies in any case and at all times to you as a person. If you earlier visa is a type C Schengen visa, then it can't grant you more than 90 days of stay in the Schengen area in any 180 days. Your new visa does not change anything to that either. You can stay 30 days on this visa but in any case not more than 90 days at once. Also note that it's not 90 days during the period of validity of the visa, it's 90 days in *any* 180 days.

Also note that **a two-entry visa is not a multiple-entry visa** so Denmark did not have to accept your application for a new visa early. But if it did issue a visa, the point is moot. Incidentally, you got very strange visa. It seems highly unusual to grant such a long two-entry visa and then revert back to a short one-entry visa.

Comment: the original statment from official website is: If you have a visa that is valid for several entries for at least 180 days you can hand in an application for a new visa before the current visa expires.---They didn't say "multiple entry ", but "several entries"

Comment: @Mary There is another paragraph further down the page with “multiple” and “six months” and that's also the terminology used in the regulation. In any case, “several” implies “more than two” in English. The main distinction in the Schengen visa code (which is the actual regulation) is between one and two-entry visas on the one hand and multiple-entry visas on the other hand.