# Travelling on a Two-Entry Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

[From the New to Denmark Website,](http://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/visa/duration/how_long.htm)

If you have a visa that is valid for several entries for at least 180 days you can hand in an application for a new visa before the current visa expires.

1. My current one is two-entry visa. Is it several-entry visa?
2. I have used one entry, one entry unused. Then I can hand in the application for the new visa (back-to-back visa of the current one, no gap between them) before the current one expires? If I choose to do so, will my current one be cancelled by embassy?
3. I plan to enter EU on Nov, exit it on early Dec. (current one expires on 12/31/2014), re-enter EU on 1/1/2015 using the new visa. Should I write the visa officer my plan when applying for the new visa? (so that VO won't cancel my current one.)

Comment: Do you have a visa or not? Your previous question implied that you did already. Do you plan to stay in the EU over new year or not?

Answer (score 1):

1. I already answered question 1 in my answer to [your earlier question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34467/short-term-visa-rules-stated-in-denmark-website/34472). In the regulation (the actual legal text), there is a distinction between one-entry and two-entry visas on the one hand and multiple-entry visas on the other hand. While “several” does imply “more than two” in English, the terminology “several-entry visa” is not used.
2. You can always apply, the risk would be that the consulate declines to process the application (most likely, nothing lost) or even rejects it (in this case you would lose the visa fee and there would be a record of the rejection). If they do annul your current visa, they can issue a new visa starting before the end of the current one so that might actually solve your problem.
3. Always detail your plan as completely as possible to ensure you get the right visa and can't be accused of fraud.

---

If you still have doubts regarding the terminology, article 15 (2) of the Schengen visa code reads:

> Applicants for a uniform visa for more than two entries (multiple entries) shall prove that they are in possession of adequate and valid travel medical insurance covering the period of their first intended visit.

and article 24 includes the sentence

> A visa may be issued for one, two or multiple entries.

Comment: hi Relaxed, thank you so much for the answer.I found a FAQ from Danish embassy website. Question:  I already hold a valid Schengen visa (have not used up all the days on the visa), but wish to apply for a complement new visa. What do I do? Answer
You must submit a normal application for a new visa at the embassy of the issuing country.

Comment: Relaxed, based on that FAQ, do you think I can apply for a new back-to-back visa before my current one expires?